# NodeJS testing on Xcode emulators

Tags: xcode, mac-address

I am working on a NodeJS application which needs to identify unique mobile devices. To achieve this I am using the **getmac** package to retrieve the macaddress for the client device.

My problem is, for now I am testing with virtual devices from Xcode on my Mac. What I found is all the emulators all have the same macaddress --- which is the macaddress from my computer.

I wonder if there is something else I can use to uniquely identify a mobile device(real or emulated) **OR** is there a way to get Xcode to produce fake and unique macaddresses?